# Download website source through Socks4 using Winsock

Tags: c++, networking, socket, tcp

I just have started to introduce myself into network programming using C++. So I started with Winsock. The code I made is compiled with MinGW and works perfectly!

As a beginner, the main purpose of code was to do what I wanted. Now it's time to go to next level!

The program will download a webpage source using a given socket and the website address/ip and port. After the connection to socks4 is established, the program sends a packet telling to associate with destination server.
Now a "GET" request is send to sock and it return the response from server.

So far so good and we have the following code:
**main.cpp**

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "util.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{   
    //Socks4 info
    u_short sockPort = 1080;
    std::string sockIp = "xx.xx.xx.xx";

    //Destination info
    u_short destPort = 80;
    std::string destIPorURL = "checkip.dyndns.com";

    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData)==0)
    {
        if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) < 2)
        {
            cout << "WSA Version error!";
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "WSA Startup Failed";
        return -1;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Init socket for socks4
    cout << "Initialize sock_addr for socks4 connection...";
    sockaddr_in sock;
    sock.sin_family = AF_INET;                      // host byte order
    sock.sin_port = htons( sockPort );              // short, network byte order
    if(!utils::getHostIP(sock.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, sockIp)) // Write ip address in the right format
    {
        cout << "fail";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;

    //Creating socket handler
    cout << "Creating socket handler...";
    SOCKET hSocketSock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    if( (hSocketSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        cout << "fail";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Init socket for destination server
    cout << "Initialize sock_addr for destination server...";
    sockaddr_in dest;
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = htons( destPort );
    if(!utils::getHostIP(dest.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, destIPorURL)) // Write ip address in the right format
    {
        cout << "fail";
        return -1;
    }
    memset( &(dest.sin_zero), '\0', 8 );
    cout << "done" << endl;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Time to make connection to socks
    cout << "Connecting to sock server...";
    if(connect(hSocketSock, reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&sock), sizeof(sock)) != 0)
    {
        cout << "failed";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;

    //We are connected now to our socket!
    //All we have to do is to send our desires.
    //From now, the things differ from SOCKS4 to SOCKS5.
    //So, the code below apply only for SOCKS4!

    //So, we'll start with SOCKS4
    //Documentation: http://www.openssh.com/txt/socks4.protocol
    //The packet we have to build
    //         +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+....+----+
    //         | VN | CD | DSTPORT |      DSTIP        | USERID       |NULL|
    //         +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+....+----+
    //# of bytes: 1    1      2              4           variable       1


    //This packet is meant to inform socks server who's the destination we want to communicate with.
    char *initPacket = new char[9]; //9 because we don't use auth.

    initPacket[0] = 4; //Sock version we use is 4
    initPacket[1] = 1; //Connect code
    memcpy(initPacket + 2, &dest.sin_port, 2); //Copy port into
    memcpy(initPacket + 4, &dest.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr, 4); //Copy ip address
    initPacket[8] = 0; //No username for auth provided

    //Sending our packet!
    cout << "Sending init packet to socks...";
    if(send(hSocketSock, initPacket, 9, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cout << "fail";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;

    //Don't need init packet anymore as we have send it.
    delete[] initPacket;

    //We want a replay. This will tell us if the sock is able to communicate with destination
    char replay[8];          //WHY 8? Because of table below :)
    memset(&replay, 0, 8);

    //Reading the response
    cout << "Reading reaponse from sock...";
    //if(recv(hSocketSock, replay, strlen((const char *)replay), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    if(recv(hSocketSock, replay, 8, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        "fail";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;

    //         Expected response format:
    //         +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
    //         | VN | CD | DSTPORT |      DSTIP        |
    //         +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
    //# of bytes: 1    1      2              4
    //    VN is the version of the reply code and should be 0. CD is the result
    //    code with one of the following values:
    //
    //    90: request granted
    //    91: request rejected or failed
    //    92: request rejected becasue SOCKS server cannot connect to identd on the client
    //    93: request rejected because the client program and identd report different user-ids.

    //So, we have to check if replay is ok :)
    cout << "Checking replay version code...";
    if(replay[0] != 0)
    {
        cout << "fail - " << (int)replay[0];
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "ok" << endl;

    //Returned code: 90 = access granted
    cout << "Checking replay returned code...";
    if(replay[1] != 90)
    {
        cout << "failed - " << (int)replay[1];
        return -1;
    }
    cout << (int)replay[1] << " - ok" << endl;

    //Those being said, if everithing is ok, we can use @hSocketSock handler to send/recv data.
    //Let's download the content of an webpage:
    std::string headers = "GET " + destIPorURL + " HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + utils::getHostFromUrl(destIPorURL) + "\r\n\r\n";

    //Send our request
    cout << endl << "Sending custom request...";
    int sendResult = send(hSocketSock, headers.c_str(), headers.length(), 0);
    if(sendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << sendResult <<  "-  failed";
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "done!" << endl;

    std::string fullResp = "";
    char buffer[128];

    cout << "Reading response from server...";
    while(true)
    {
        int retval = recv(hSocketSock, buffer, strlen((const char *)buffer), 0);
        if(retval == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if(retval == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "failed";
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[retval] = 0;
            fullResp +=  buffer;
        }
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;
    cout << "What we have got:" << endl << fullResp;


    //Make clean!
    if(hSocketSock != INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        closesocket(hSocketSock);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you may have seen, the **util.hpp** contain some namespaces with the following functions used in program (and other useful functions):

```
std::string getHostFromUrl(std::string &url);
bool getHostIP(unsigned long &ipAddr, std::string urlOrHostnameOrIp);
```

Don't need a review for this. However I will post content of **util.cpp** and **util.hpp** in case someone wants to test.

**util.hpp:**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace utils
{
    std::string getHostFromUrl(std::string &url);
    bool getHostIP(unsigned long &ipAddr, std::string urlOrHostnameOrIp);

    namespace IPAddr
    {
        bool isValidIPv4(std::string &ip);
        std::string reverseIpAddress(std::string ip);
        std::string decimalToDottedIp(unsigned long ip);
        unsigned long stripToDecimal(std::string &ip);
    }

    namespace strings
    {
        std::vector<std::string> split(std::string &s, char delim);
        std::string removeSubstrs(std::string &source, std::string pattern);
    }
};
```

**util.cpp**

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "util.hpp"

#define cout std::cout
#define endl std::endl

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   _   _                                                         _   _ _
//  | \ | | __ _ _ __ ___   ___  ___ _ __   __ _  ___ ___    _   _| |_(_) |___
//  |  \| |/ _` | '_ ` _ \ / _ \/ __| '_ \ / _` |/ __/ _ \  | | | | __| | / __|
//  | |\  | (_| | | | | | |  __/\__ \ |_) | (_| | (_|  __/  | |_| | |_| | \__ \
//  |_| \_|\__,_|_| |_| |_|\___||___/ .__/ \__,_|\___\___|   \__,_|\__|_|_|___/
//                                  |_|
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

bool utils::getHostIP(unsigned long &ipAddr, std::string url)
{
    HOSTENT *pHostent;
    std::string hostname = getHostFromUrl(url);

    if( utils::IPAddr::isValidIPv4(hostname) )
    {
        //IP Address must be reversed in order to be compatible with sockAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr
        //example: 192.168.1.2 => 2.1.168.192
        hostname = utils::IPAddr::reverseIpAddress(hostname);
        ipAddr =  utils::IPAddr::stripToDecimal(hostname);
        return true;
    }

    if (!(pHostent = gethostbyname(hostname.c_str())))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (pHostent->h_addr_list && pHostent->h_addr_list[0])
    {
        ipAddr = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long *>(pHostent->h_addr_list[0]);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::string utils::getHostFromUrl(std::string &url)
{
    std::string urlcopy = url;

    urlcopy = utils::strings::removeSubstrs(urlcopy, "http://");
    urlcopy = utils::strings::removeSubstrs(urlcopy, "www.");
    urlcopy = utils::strings::removeSubstrs(urlcopy, "https://");
    urlcopy = urlcopy.substr(0, urlcopy.find("/"));

    return urlcopy;
}

//   ___  ____        _        _      _
// | _ _||  _ \      / \    __| |  __| | _ __  ___  ___  ___
//   | | | |_) |    / _ \  / _` | / _` || '__|/ _ \/ __|/ __|
//   | | |  __/    / ___ \| (_| || (_| || |  |  __/\__ \\__ \
//  |___||_|      /_/   \_\\__,_| \__,_||_|   \___||___/|___/

bool utils::IPAddr::isValidIPv4(std::string &ipv4)
{
    const std::string address = ipv4;

    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    int k = 0;
    arr.push_back(std::string());
    for (std::string::const_iterator i = address.begin(); i != address.end(); ++i)
    {
        if (*i == '.')
        {
            ++k;
            arr.push_back(std::string());
            if (k == 4)
            {
                return false;
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (*i >= '0' && *i <= '9')
        {
            arr[k] += *i;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (arr[k].size() > 3)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (k != 3)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != 4; ++i)
    {
        const char* nPtr = arr[i].c_str();
        char* endPtr = 0;
        const unsigned long a = ::strtoul(nPtr, &endPtr, 10);
        if (nPtr == endPtr)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (a > 255)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

std::string utils::IPAddr::reverseIpAddress(std::string ip)
{
    std::vector<std::string> octeti = utils::strings::split(ip, '.');
    return (octeti[3] + "." + octeti[2] + "." + octeti[1] + "." + octeti[0]);
}

unsigned long utils::IPAddr::stripToDecimal(std::string &ip)
{
    unsigned long a,b,c,d,base10IP;
    sscanf(ip.c_str(), "%lu.%lu.%lu.%lu", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    // Do calculations to convert IP to base 10
    a *= 16777216;
    b *= 65536;
    c *= 256;
    base10IP = a + b + c + d;

    return base10IP;
}

std::string utils::IPAddr::decimalToDottedIp(unsigned long ipAddr)
{
    unsigned short a, b, c, d;
    std::ostringstream os ;
    std::string ip = "";

    a = (ipAddr & (0xff << 24)) >> 24;
    b = (ipAddr & (0xff << 16)) >> 16;
    c = (ipAddr & (0xff << 8)) >> 8;
    d = ipAddr & 0xff;

    os << d << "." << c << "." << b << "." << a;
    ip = os.str();

    return ip;
}

//   ____   _          _
//  / ___| | |_  _ __ (_) _ __    __ _  ___
//  \___ \ | __|| '__|| || '_ \  / _` |/ __|
//   ___) || |_ | |   | || | | || (_| |\__ \
//  |____/  \__||_|   |_||_| |_| \__, ||___/
//                               |___/

std::vector<std::string> utils::strings::split(std::string &s, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> elems;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
    {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}

std::string utils::strings::removeSubstrs(std::string &input, std::string pattern)
{
    std::string source = input;
    std::string::size_type n = pattern.length();

    for (std::string::size_type i = source.find(pattern); i != std::string::npos; i = source.find(pattern))
    {
        source.erase(i, n);
    }
    return source;
}
```

The thing is that I have some plans for some projects which uses sockets and I want to get a good start!

I think that the code I wrote is not so easy to understand. For me it's easy but for the others my not!

Hope it is not to soon to say that but I want to write some professional code. So, be as critical as possible!

PS: Not sure if it helps, but the output looks like the following:
[image]